# Issues with compiling Caffe with cuDNN

Tags: cuda, caffe

i am trying to compile caffe on ubuntu14 with 750ti geforce gpu but i cant. i installed the cudnn library in /usr/local/cuda/lib64 and the cudnn.h header file in /usr/local/cuda/include still there seems to be a problem. i really think enabling the cudNN=1 in Makefile.config

```
# cuDNN acceleration switch (uncomment to build with cuDNN).
USE_CUDNN := 1
```

thats where the problem is. What exactly are these errors?

```
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:65:5: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     int n, int c, int h, int w,
     ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:65:12: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     int n, int c, int h, int w,
            ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:65:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     int n, int c, int h, int w,
                   ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:65:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     int n, int c, int h, int w,
                          ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:66:5: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     int stride_n, int stride_c, int stride_h, int stride_w) {
     ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:66:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     int stride_n, int stride_c, int stride_h, int stride_w) {
                   ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:66:33: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     int stride_n, int stride_c, int stride_h, int stride_w) {
                                 ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:66:47: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     int stride_n, int stride_c, int stride_h, int stride_w) {
                                               ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:72:29: error: variable or field ‘setTensor4dDesc’ declared void
 inline void setTensor4dDesc(cudnnTensor4dDescriptor_t* desc,
                             ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:72:29: error: ‘cudnnTensor4dDescriptor_t’ was not declared in this scope
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:72:56: error: ‘desc’ was not declared in this scope
 inline void setTensor4dDesc(cudnnTensor4dDescriptor_t* desc,
                                                        ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:73:5: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     int n, int c, int h, int w) {
     ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:73:12: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     int n, int c, int h, int w) {
            ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:73:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     int n, int c, int h, int w) {
                   ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:73:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     int n, int c, int h, int w) {
                          ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:97:5: error: ‘cudnnTensor4dDescriptor_t’ has not been declared
     cudnnTensor4dDescriptor_t bottom, cudnnFilterDescriptor_t filter,
     ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp: In function ‘void caffe::cudnn::setConvolutionDesc(cudnnConvolutionStruct**, int, cudnnFilterDescriptor_t, int, int, int, int)’:
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:100:70: error: there are no arguments to ‘cudnnSetConvolutionDescriptor’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘cudnnSetConvolutionDescriptor’ must be available [-fpermissive]
       pad_h, pad_w, stride_h, stride_w, 1, 1, CUDNN_CROSS_CORRELATION));
                                                                      ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:11:28: note: in definition of macro ‘CUDNN_CHECK’
     cudnnStatus_t status = condition; \
                            ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:100:70: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
       pad_h, pad_w, stride_h, stride_w, 1, 1, CUDNN_CROSS_CORRELATION));
                                                                      ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:11:28: note: in definition of macro ‘CUDNN_CHECK’
     cudnnStatus_t status = condition; \
                            ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp: In function ‘void caffe::cudnn::createPoolingDesc(cudnnPoolingStruct**, caffe::PoolingParameter_PoolMethod, cudnnPoolingMode_t*, int, int, int, int)’:
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:119:27: error: there are no arguments to ‘cudnnSetPoolingDescriptor’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘cudnnSetPoolingDescriptor’ must be available [-fpermissive]
         stride_h, stride_w));
                           ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:11:28: note: in definition of macro ‘CUDNN_CHECK’
     cudnnStatus_t status = condition; \
                            ^
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/syncedmem.o] Error 1
```

I tested CUDA sample and GPU is working fine with cuda. Here is the result...

```
root@pbu-OptiPlex-740-Enhanced:/home/pbu/NVIDIA_CUDA-6.5_Samples/0_Simple/matrixMul# ./matrixMul
[Matrix Multiply Using CUDA] - Starting...
GPU Device 0: "GeForce GTX 750 Ti" with compute capability 5.0

MatrixA(320,320), MatrixB(640,320)
Computing result using CUDA Kernel...
done
Performance= 157.82 GFlop/s, Time= 0.831 msec, Size= 131072000 Ops, WorkgroupSize= 1024 threads/block
Checking computed result for correctness: Result = PASS

Note: For peak performance, please refer to the matrixMulCUBLAS example.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A version of Caffe that works with cuDNNv2 is available from [S. Layton's github page](https://github.com/slayton58/caffe).

His Caffe master branch works with cuDNNv2. You can download it from the github page.

He made a pull request to the official Caffe github and the full discussion is available [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/1739) if you want the details.

Comment: Please don't just add links, if you want to provide a good answers you need to give a complete suggestion, the links would be only for deep informations purposes. otherwise you can just leave a comment

Comment: I edited my answer but there is not much more to say other then download from the link and use the corresponding version...I'll be happy to answer if there are other questions....

Comment: thats perfect now :) but FYI the OP already answered his question ;)

Comment: I think it is useful to know there is a working version for v2.

Comment: Yes, i do agree with you

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded cuDNN R1 and now its working. Looks cudNN R2 latest one is not compatible with caffe.